# How to set status code for certain URLs with IF in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, apache2.4, response-headers

I have URLs like `https://example.com/page/1234/` and `https://example.com/page/9876/`. For these URLs i want set certain status code via htaccess (Apache 2.4).

I try to do it with

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ (1234|9876)\/$">
    Header set Status "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone"
</If>
```

but i seem to have an error in the code, because i don't see the new status code as response in developer tools. How should it be done on the correct way?

**PS**: i can't use 'rewriteRule' - this kind of setting 410 triggers ErrorDocument, what i don't want. For these two URLs i only want to set the status code. For other URLs, which get 410 on the native way, ErrorDocument shold be triggered.

Comment: "For these two URLs i only want to set the status code" - What are you expecting (or wanting) to be sent back in the response body? Are you wanting the "normal page response" (as generated by your application), but with a 410 HTTP status?

Comment: _Aisde:_ "but i seem to have an error in the code, **because i don't see the new status code** as response" - The code as posted is syntactically invalid - you should have seen a 500 Internal Server Error?!

Comment: @MrWhite 100% correct: usual page, but with response status 410 Gone

Comment: @MrWhite don't see 500 :( But don't see 410 too - just usual page with 200

Comment: You should check your error log. If what you posted is not throwing a visible error then it would lead me to assume you are not on Apache? Perhaps LiteSpeed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you wanting the "normal page response" (as generated by your application), but with a 410 HTTP status?
> 100% correct: usual page, but with response status 410 Gone

Triggering the 410 response in Apache will always serve the appropriate Apache `ErrorDocument`. What you could do is set the 410 `ErrorDocument` itself to the same URL and trigger the 410 response in the usual way. However, we need to be careful not to create a "rewrite-loop".

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/page/(1234|9876)/$# && %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} == ''">
    # Capture the URL-path after the slash prefix
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(.+)" REL_URL_PATH=$1

    # Dynamic ErrorDocument to the same as the requested URL
    # The slash prefix in the directive is necessary to be seen as a local URL-path
    ErrorDocument 410 /%{reqenv:REL_URL_PATH}

    # Trigger 410 Gone
    RewriteRule ^ - [G]
</If>
```

This requires Apache 2.4.13+ due to the expression syntax in the `ErrorDocument` directive.

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` in the `<If>` expression is necessary to avoid a rewrite loop (500 response) when serving the error document itself.

The alternative is to set the 410 response code in your application itself, which would be my preference.

*Aside:* Setting the `Status` HTTP response header, which appears to be what you are trying to do in the question simply sets a `Status` HTTP response header, it does not change the HTTP response status itself. (The `Status` response header is a non-standard header used by CGI scripts to indicate to the webserver what response code should be set.)

---

> **UPDATE:** in my tests if i add to htaccess only the rule `Header set Status "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone"`, without any condition, it works like i expect: all URLs from this directory get the header `410 Gone` but are still available (ErrorDocument isn't triggered).

Maybe your server is configured differently and is perhaps behind a proxy that sets the HTTP response? But as mentioned above, that simply sets a `Status` HTTP response header, it doesn't change the HTTP response code on the request. It doesn't "work" on my test server. (If used at all, the `Status` header doesn't normally contain the protocol, it would simply be `Header set Status "410 Gone"`.)

So, if this does work for you then you just need to "correct" the syntax in your Apache expression.

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/(1234|9876)/$#">
    Header set Status "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone"
</If>
```

The above matches any URL that simply ends with `/1234/` or `/9876/`. Or, to be more specific and match the entire URL use `m#^/page/(1234|9876)/$#`. This uses the alternative syntax for delimiting regex (ie. `m#<regex>#`), instead of using slashes (ie. `/<regex>/`), in order to avoid having to escape the slashes in the pattern.

Alternatively, you don't need the Apache expression, you could use `SetEnvIf` and set the header conditionally based on the environment variable.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/(1234|9876)/$" GONE=1
Header set Status "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone" env=GONE
```

Comment: Updated/rewritten answer with a workable solution. It feels a bit "hacky" though.

Comment: in my tests if i add to htaccess only the rule `Header set Status "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone"`, without any condition, it works like i expect: all URLs from this directory get the header `410 Gone` but are still available (ErrorDocument isn't triggered).

Comment: "it works like i expect" - In that case, this would seem to be reasonably unique to your server config since that only sets a `Status` HTTP response header, it doesn't actually set the HTTP response code on the request (as mentioned in my answer) - so there must be something else that does this. If this is working for you then I've updated my answer with an alternative solution (fixing the code in your question) and added further explanation.

Comment: your last updates correspond 100% with my idea - i even tested it, but, as often, failed on syntax...

Answer (score 3):

You may use this block with `<If>` expression that uses default `ErrorDocument 410` for a specific URL pattern:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/(1234|9876)/?$#">
    # only for above URL disable ErrorDocument
    ErrorDocument 410 default
    # set status=410
    RewriteRule . - [L,G]
</If>
```

Comment: No, i can't do so - because this kind triggers ErrorDocument. But i want only set the status code.

Comment: Setting the status code is same as using `R=...`

Comment: I tested this behavior, it works as i describe. And i do want ErrorDocument, but not in these two cases. For these two URLs i only want to set status code.

Comment: `ErrorDocument 410 default`will display server's own 410 page, correct? This is what i want to avoid.

Comment: ok please check my updated answer. It sets `410` for a matching pattern with triggering `ErrorDocument` handling

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^page/(1234|9876)/?$ - [NC,R=410,L]
```